# Best way to mark Client Offline using Web-Service

Tags: c#, web-services

Currently I'm working with a Web-Service where Client's Continually should update Data .
So the WebService has a `List<Client> clients;` where it stores Connected Client's :

```
[WebMethod]
public string Connect(Size desktopsize)
{
  Client clienti = new Client();
  clienti.ID = "Client_" + Counter.ToString();
  clienti.Desktopsize = desktopsize;
  clienti.Lastupdate = DateTime.Now;
  Counter++;
  clients.Add(clienti);
  return clienti.ID;
}
```

so every client has an ID ,and continue Updating it's Data's.
I need to mark a Client Offline ,than when the Last Update of a specific Client was 1 minute ago .(Im also updating the UpdateTime every time when a value is changed
like :

```
public bool SingleClick
{
  get
  {
    bool tmpBolean = singleclick;
    singleclick = false;
    return tmpBolean;
  }
  set
  {
    this.lastupdate = DateTime.Now;
    singleclick = value;
  }
}
```

First i used to create a Thread at Client

```
private void CheckOnlinestate()
{
  while (isRunning)
  {
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - lastupdate;
    if (ts.TotalMinutes >= 1)
    {
      isRunning = false;
      this.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

than at WebService a thread which monitor's if Client should remove from list:

```
public void CheckClients()
{
  while (true)
  {
    foreach (Client c in clients)
    {
      if (c.ShouldDispose)
      {
        clients.Remove(c);
      }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(200);
  }
}
```

So the issue is ,how to use this method into a Thread Correctly ,should i Create and Start the thread at WebService Constructor ,or there is a better way to do that.
I cant imagine the best way how to remove a specific Client from `List<Client> clients;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache` class instead of implementing your own.

There are some other problems with your code. Accesses to `Counter` and `clients` are uncontrolled which are shared among threads. You should use some sync. mechanism such as `lock` while accessing these objects ( *You can forget my comment about `clients` if you already declared it as `ConcurrentDictionary`*)